# Rails Layout Is Not Used

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app if the user is signed in I show one header, if they are not signed in I show another header.

In my `application.html.erb` file I have:

```
<!-- If user is signed in and registered, show the signed_in_header  -->
<% if user_signed_in? && current_user.registration_complete? %>
  <%= render :partial => 'layouts/signed_in_header' %>
<% else %>
<!-- If not signed in, then show the signed_out_header  -->
  <%= render :partial => 'layouts/signed_out_header' %>
<% end %>
```

My app is not ready yet, so I want to show a "Coming soon" page. In my controller I have:

```
def index
  render 'users/sessions/coming', :layout => 'devise'
end
```

And in my routes.rb:

```
root :to => "home#index"
```

which does indeed show the `coming.html.erb` file. But I want this page displayed just by itself, with no header. At present the `signed_out_header` is showing. Any straight forward way to do this?

Comment: you specify the `devise` layout, which is not the `application` layout.. not surprising that the `application` layout isn't being used

Comment: Yes, in fact, that piece of signed_out_header in my code is irrelevant. I thought it made sense because my app works as intended - if signed in, app did one thing, if not signed in, it did another. But in my layouts/devise file I can see '<%#= render :partial => 'layouts/signed_out_header' %>' So I comment that out and my header's not there, which is what I want, cheers.